# EXC BAD ACCESS Error Building QuantLib C++ Program on Xcode

Tags: c++, boost, quantlib

I have built Boost (1.57) on my local machine (Mac OS X 10.10.1) using clang++. I have also built a quantitative finance library QuantLib. QuantLib references Boost within its implementation.

I created a simple C++ program in XCode to test the QuantLib library. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {        
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This code builds fine (albeit with some warnings which I can ignore for now). However, when running the code, I get a thread exception in the Boost library (erf.hpp) as follows:

```
#0  0x00000001003f73b7 in long double boost::math::detail::erf_imp<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::promote_double<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> >(long double, bool, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::promote_double<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> const&, mpl_::int_<64> const&) at /usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp:423
#1  0x00000001003f8928 in boost::math::tools::promote_args<long double, float, float, float, float, float>::type boost::math::erf<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::promote_double<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> >(long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::promote_double<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> const&) [inlined] at /usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp:1081
#2  0x00000001003f8916 in boost::math::detail::erf_initializer<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::promote_double<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>, mpl_::int_<64> >::init::do_init(mpl_::int_<64> const&) at /usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp:1009
#3  0x00000001003f987b in boost::math::detail::erf_initializer<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::promote_double<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>, mpl_::int_<64> >::init::init() [inlined] at /usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp:994
#4  0x00000001003f9876 in boost::math::detail::erf_initializer<long double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::promote_float<false>, boost::math::policies::promote_double<false>, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>, mpl_::int_<64> >::init::init() [inlined] at /usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp:995
#5  0x00000001003f9876 in __cxx_global_var_init at /usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp:1038
#6  0x00007fff5fc12ceb in ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) ()
#7  0x00007fff5fc12e78 in ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) ()
#8  0x00007fff5fc0f871 in ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) ()
#9  0x00007fff5fc0f806 in ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) ()
#10 0x00007fff5fc0f6f8 in ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) ()
#11 0x00007fff5fc0f969 in ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) ()
#12 0x00007fff5fc02245 in dyld::initializeMainExecutable() ()
#13 0x00007fff5fc05be1 in dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) ()
#14 0x00007fff5fc01276 in dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) ()
#15 0x00007fff5fc01036 in _dyld_start ()
```

More specifically, it fails at this point in the erf.hpp file;

```
  else
  {
     // Max Error found at long double precision =   1.623299e-20
     // Maximum Deviation Found:                     4.326e-22
     // Expected Error Term:                         -4.326e-22
     // Maximum Relative Change in Control Points:   1.474e-04
     static const T Y = 1.044948577880859375f;
     static const T P[] = {


/** THREAD EXCEPTION HERE **/        
BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, 0.0834305892146531988966),// FAILS HERE WITH EXC_BAD_ACCESS    


        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, -0.338097283075565413695),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, -0.0509602734406067204596),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, -0.00904906346158537794396),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, -0.000489468651464798669181),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, -0.200305626366151877759e-4),
     };
     static const T Q[] = {    
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, 1.0),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, 0.455817300515875172439),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, 0.0916537354356241792007),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, 0.0102722652675910031202),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, 0.000650511752687851548735),
        BOOST_MATH_BIG_CONSTANT(T, 64, 0.189532519105655496778e-4),
     };
     result = z * (Y + tools::evaluate_polynomial(P, T(z * z)) / tools::evaluate_polynomial(Q, T(z * z)));
  }
```

From looking at another post on SO, I think this maybe a Xcode issue but I don't have another machine with another operating system to verify. In any case, I don't see why Xcode would interfere at this level of code so I'm thinking it maybe due to clang but it's just conjecture. Any help to fix this or shed light on the issue would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

Removing `#include <ql/experimental/all.hpp>` allows the program to run. Question is why is the inclusion of this header causing runtime failure in Boost.

Comment: Are you *sure* you can ignore the warnings? Warnings are often an indication of possible UB, and UB can often lead to crashes.

Comment: I'm seeing 13 warnings of type value conversion issues. Typical example is implicit conversion from unsigned long to int. But this is inside the QuantLib library code and not the Boost library.

Comment: The library you use in its turn is using Boost, and if it does something it should not do then the problem may *manifest* in Boost. If you look at that stack-trace for example, go up a few levels and you're no longer in Boost.

Comment: Are you compiling both library and program in the same way? There were reports of errors of this kind when the library was compiled as C++03 and the program as C++11, (or possibly the other way around); see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/36032

Comment: @LuigiBallabio, yes I am compiling both library and program with the same compiler and switches.